# How to visualise ndarray Rust in VSCode?

Tags: c++, rust, vscode-debugger

I am using VSCode to develop my rust application which contains lots of NDArray. When I set breakpoint and watch the NDArray variable, it is only showing pointers. I don't know how to view the content. I tried both cppvsdbg & lldb (vscode-codelldb) and both has same issue? Is there any command I can type in debug console to expand the variable?

[image]

Comment: There's also an issue raised about this on NDarray's Github page: https://github.com/rust-ndarray/ndarray/issues/827

Comment: Yes It was me you raised Github issue and thanks for reminding. I will add my findings as an answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am now able to visualise it using below natvis,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">
<Type Name="ndarray::ArrayBase&lt;*,*&gt;">
      <DisplayString>{{Modified by Selva}}</DisplayString>
      <Expand HideRawView="false">  
            <ArrayItems>  
                  <Direction>Forward</Direction>  
                  <Rank>sizeof(dim.index)/sizeof(*dim.index)</Rank>
                  <Size>(int)dim.index[$i]</Size>  
                  <!-- <Size>$i==0?(int)dim.index[0]:(int)dim.index[1]</Size>   -->
                  <ValuePointer>data.ptr.pointer</ValuePointer>  
            </ArrayItems>  
      </Expand>
</Type>
</AutoVisualizer>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained how to use this or provided a link to where this information can be found.